# Сколько живут Cookie?

Tags: php, cookie, сессия

При авторизации `Сессия` создает `куку` на определенное время, если не указать иное. Как можно узнать ее время жизни которое там стоит по умолчанию?

Comment: Посмотреть? (Как я понимаю, интерес со стороны клиента, и код на сервере не виден). Либо там, где браузер хранит куки, либо (если уж совсем в лоб) сниффером (set-cookie max-age). см rfc6265. Ecли же интересно, что происходит при setcookie с expires=0,  то в описании setcookie указано, что до конца сеанса браузера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию в основном - 0. Кукя умирает сразу после создания, но это завистит напрямую от файла конфигурации php.ini. Легче всего установить кукю так:

> `setcookie('Login','bob',time()+(3600*24))`

В данном коде к куки записывается "Login" со значением "bob". Данная кукя будет жить ровно сутки(в часе 3600 секунд, а в сутках их - 24)

Answer (score 1):

Если мне не изменяет память, если у куков TTL равен нулю, то живут они ровно до момента закрытия браузера.